# How to store different character set in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two column name:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `test` */

insert  into `test`(`id`,`name`) values (1,'Potvrzení koupě');
```

I want to store the correct text which is "PotvrzenÃ­ koupÄ›".

How can I store this way text in my table?

Comment: What your problem? It working fine check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f82e/1

Comment: Not working its giving same result. i want  "PotvrzenÃ­ koupÄ›".

Comment: I given link have you check it?

Comment: Then what a problem it gives same as you stored in table

Comment: CAST('Potvrzení koupě' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) using this and result should be  "PotvrzenÃ­ koupÄ›".

Comment: Sorry! I dont understand what actually you want?

Comment: You can try to store it ascaped as Potvrzen\u00ED koup\u011B